# How to select topology for neural network?

Tags: neural-network

I was given a target function to design neural network and train: (y = (x1 ∧ x2) ∨ (x3 ∧ x4))

The number of input and number of output seems obvious (4 and 1). And the training data can use truth table.

However, in order to train as a multilayer artificial neural network, I need to choose number of hidden units. May I know where can I find some general guideline for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You problem is linearly separable so you can use a single layer perceptron. 
Hidden units are necessary only for non linear problems (xor is a classic example).

As for general guidelines, I don't think anyone has ever needed more than one hidden layer. Also the number of neurons in the hidden layer doesn't need to exceed the number of inputs.

Comment: On StackExchange, such short answers are usually (with rare exceptions) preferred in a form of a comment. Posting answer implies a more detailed/comprehensive treatment of a topic. Just FYI.

Comment: @Alex S Kinman multi hidden layer is common in deep learning architecture.

Comment: @Aleksandr Blekh what if a question doesn't need a long answer at all? do you have a reference where your comment based on, meta, faq etc? thx

Comment: @Xin , I don't know enough about deep neural networks. But for traditional neural networks, the universal function approximation theorem states that a multilayer network with a single hidden layer can approximate any continuous decision function. I am curious, are there any results proving that DNN have more representational power than regular ANN?

Comment: @Xin: The following relevant SE Meta answers should give you the right impression, hopefully: [on what is considered a good answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129021/263279) and [on converting a comment to an answer by expanding the former](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248125/263279). I'm sure that there many more guidelines on Meta, but that should be enough.

Comment: This is not a linearly separable problem because a single hyperplane cannot describe the decision boundary. A `4x2x1` network can describe the boundary. The two hidden layer neurons describe the two `AND` surfaces and the output neuron is the logical `OR` of the two `AND` surfaces.

Comment: Also, the statement that "the number of neurons in the hidden layer doesn't need to exceed the number of inputs" is false. Consider the simple problem of class 1 covering the x-y plane with a triangular region cut out for class 2. There are only two inputs for this network but it requires at least three hidden layer neurons to describe the triangular decision surface. One can easily construct examples that require *many* more hidden layer neurons than inputs (e.g., if class 2 lies in multiple triangular regions).

Comment: @Bogatron : I actually drew the decision boundary for the variables (2 by 2) , and there was a linear decision boundary. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "2 by 2". The decision boundary for `y = (x1 ∧ x2) ∨ (x3 ∧ x4)` is in a 4-D space. "Linearly separable" implies that a single 4-D hyperplane can represent the decision boundary but that is not the case. There is no linear decision boundary that can correctly classify all 16 `y` values for this logical function.

Comment: @bogatron (not disputing you, just trying to figure out my error) in the 3-D feature space with dimensions [x1,x2,(x3*x4)] , there is a plane representing the decision boundary. Why won't that translate into a 4-D hyperplane in the [x1,x2,x3,x4] space ?

Comment: @AlexSKinman I deleted my previous comment because the 3-D case I gave was a bad example (that one is indeed linearly separable). I tried training a 4x1 network on the `y = (x1 ∧ x2) ∨ (x3 ∧ x4)` problem numerous times and could not get it to learn the function (the best it would do was accuracy of 0.9375 (i.e., one input was always misclassified). Using a 4x2x1 network, the function was easily learned. If you believe you can construct a separating hyperplane, perhaps you could provide its coefficients (i.e., the `a` coefficients for `f(x) = a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3 + a4*x4 - a0`).